# Multiple Deployments of JaxRS App in TomEE causing DuplicateDeploymentIdException

Tags: java, jax-rs, openejb, apache-tomee

I'm trying to deploy multiple instances of our service on our staging server, all on the same TomEE instance. They all have different context paths (platform_foo, platform_bar).

I'm getting an exception:

`Caused by: org.apache.openejb.DuplicateDeploymentIdException: Application cannot be deployed as it contains deployment-ids which are in use: app: /var/www/apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.6.0/webapps/platform_foo
    UsersService
    SessionsService`

My openejb-jar.xml:

```
<openejb-jar xmlns="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1">
    <pojo-deployment class-name="jaxrs-application">
        <properties>
            cxf.jaxrs.providers = <redacted>
        </properties>
    </pojo-deployment>
</openejb-jar>
```

I tried everything from setting an ID on the `web-app` element in `web.xml`, to setting the `deployment-id` in the `openejb-jar.xml`. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone has answered a similar question that I just didn't search for hard enough.

[Tomcat / "Application cannot be deployed as it contains deployment-ids" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265762/tomcat-application-cannot-be-deployed-as-it-contains-deployment-ids-error)

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy in another folder that webapp. I had same issue in tomEE and solved with this

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11296693)

Comment: @mjp66 How is this a comment? It suggests a way to solve the issue. If you think this is a bad or wrong answer, you can downvote it. Don't misuse the LQPRQ for deletion of such answers.